# What is Function's __proto__?

Tags: javascript

[image]

I see this nice diagram and I've done some tests in my Chrome browser, but I don't know how to explain this:

```
> Function.prototype
  function Empty() {}
> Function.__proto__
  function Empty() {}
> typeof(Empty)
  "undefined"
```

What is the `function Empty() {}`, and why `Function.prototype` is a `function` not a `object` just like `Object.prototype`?

From the diagram above, it seems everything in JavaScript starts from `Object.prototype`, am I right about that?

Comment: The answer to this puzzle is that Function.__proto__.__proto__ === Object.prototype. But you won't get there through Function.constructor.prototype, because that was set to undefined (or not set at all).

Comment: +1 I always think the most straightforward way to explain something is to draw a picture/diagram and let it talk. Thanks for attaching the diagram here!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

First, the `function Empty() {}` representation is [V8](http://code.google.com/p/v8/) stuff.

In V8, the `Function.prototype` object has `"Empty`" as the value of the `Function.prototype.name` property, so I guess you are probably using the Chrome's Developer Console, and it displays the name of the function in this way.

The `name` property of function objects is `non-standard` (not part of ECMA-262), that's why we see differences between implementations.

Now, `Function.prototype` is a function, that returns always `undefined` and can accept any number of arguments, but why?. Maybe just for consistency, every built-in constructor's prototype is like that, `Number.prototype` is a `Number` object, `Array.prototype` is an `Array` object, `RegExp.prototype` is a `RegExp` object, and so on...

The only difference (for example, between any function object and `Function.prototype`) is that obviously `Function.prototype` inherits from `Object.prototype`.

> it seems everything in javascript start from Object.prototype, am I right about that?

Well, you're right `Object.prototype` is the last object of the prototype chain of most objects, but in ECMAScript 5, you can even create objects that doesn't inherit from anything (just like `Object.prototype` is), and form another inheritance chain, e.g.:

```
var parent = Object.create(null),
    child = Object.create(parent);

Object.prototype.isPrototypeOf(parent);  // false

Object.getPrototypeOf(parent);           // null
Object.getPrototypeOf(Object.prototype); // null
```

Comment: Actually I am still but curious to know about why consoles usually shows the typeof Function.prototype as Function and all other types RegExp, String ,Number as Object . I know you have mentioned it but for consistency ??
Please shed some more light on it

Comment: @Gurjit, `typeof Function.prototype == 'function'` because the `typeof` operator returns 'function' when you use it on a "callable object" (a function). And you can clearly invoke it: `Function.prototype() === undefined`.

Answer (score 8):

To integrate CMS excellent answer:

> it seems everything in javascript start from Object.prototype, am I right about that?

Absolutely, objects in JavaScript are chained up to the basic Object. The chain of inheritance works at runtime, so if a base object is modified, everything chained to it will inherit the modifications instantly. If an Object doesn't have a method or a property, the Javascript implementation will follow the prototype chain until it finds it or it will fail.

`__proto__` is a non standard accessor to the prototype, which is supported across browsers, but not by IE. Anyway is not meant to be used by application code.